# Passing String array to a function

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I am trying to pass an array to a function:

```
var array:[String] = []
// fill the array
array.append(uniqueId as String)
// pass the array to a function:
GamePrefrences.setLevelsArray(array)
```

My function is declares like this:

```
func setLevelsArray(arr:[String])
{
    GamePrefrences.levels_array = arr

}
```

But on the line i try to call the function it gives with an error:

> cannot invoke ... with argument list of type [(String)]

What is the problem? if its possible to provide brief explanation

Comment: do you know how arrays and dictionary are passed in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your function is not a class level function and you are calling the method directly using class name.

Try like this.

```
var array:[String] = []
// fill the array
array.append(uniqueId as! String)
// pass the array to a function:
GamePrefrences.setLevelsArray(array)
```

Function declaration.

```
  class func setLevelsArray(arr:[String])
    {
        GamePrefrences.levels_array = arr

    }
```

or,

```
var array:[String] = []
// fill the array
array.append(uniqueId as String)
// pass the array to a function:
let instance = GamePrefrences()//Depends on you, how you defined the initialiser.
instance.setLevelsArray(array)
```

Your function body.

```
func setLevelsArray(arr:[String])
{
    instance.levels_array = arr

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try something like this

```
func setLevelsArray(arr:[String])
{
let tempArr = arr
    GamePrefrences.levels_array = tempArr

}
```

in `Swift` `Arrays` and `Dictionary` are passed by value not by reference, therefore if you are not changing the values or assigning to any other variable then `Swift compiler` does not get the copy, instead the variable still lives in the `heap`. so before assigning i believe it is necessary to copy this into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid declaration of an empty array. Here's how to declare empty array:

```
var array = [String]()
```

Comment: we can also declare the way Michael did. :)